# How can I compare issuers of two ssl certificates?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a task to make sure that ssl client certificate and ssl server public certificate have the same issuer (local citrix). How can i achieve it?

Comment: `openssl x509 -in [file] -noout -text`